# How to add a custom serialize value in sales_flat_quote_item_option table

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, addtocart, sales-quote

> Here my code but it does't work

```
 $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($action);die;
    if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add')
    {
           //die("<br>.s");
           //$product = $observer->getProduct();
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($observer->getProduct());die;
            // add to the additional options array
            $additionalOptions = array();

                $additionalOptions[] = array(
                    'label' => 'comefrom',
                    'value' => $comefrom,
                );
            $observer->getProduct()
                ->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));


    }
```

> This additional option filed I want to add in sales_flat_quote_item_option table in a serialize form.

Comment: can you tell me which error you are facing when try above code? And which observer event you are user?

Comment: i am using checkout_cart_product_add_after observer .it doesn't create any error but this additional_option is not adding in table.i want to add this value to add in  sales_flat_quote_item_option table in serialize from